# Paint the entire area within the heatmap

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I need to paint the countries for heatmap. I have achieved that with the help of google heatmaps. 
Now, how can I paint the entire area of a country within the country boundaries without adding any more latitude longitude (in short increasing the size of json file)?

What did I do so far? Here's the reference link - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

It's not a full blown example but yeah basically the google heatmaps in action with different lat longs.

Does google has this feature? All I can see is the radius property.

Do I need to use SVG, canvas for this? What would be the approach ? Isn't there any easy approach to just extend google heatmaps to avoid re-work.

Second, How can I add custom colors based on one price property. Say, I need to color the map with blue for price range of 0-200, green for 200-400 and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible, and heatmaps are not meant to do that... you should use regions / geocharts for that:

[An example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart)

Comment: Ah man! This is a blow.  So, I don't need lat long at all I guess. No use of natural earth data therefore. So All I got to do is make a crud for regions (having country code inside country list) and then provide that country array to arrayToDataTable method. Wow ! I am done painting the regions. Thank you !